# How can I find the difference between locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(...).getTime() and now?

Tags: android, performance, math, location

I know this is more of a math question, but how can I find the time passed between locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime() and now? getTime returns milliseconds since January 1,1970.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both of the times return milliseconds since January 1, 1970 you can just subtract the one from the other to get difference in milliseconds.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
a = getLastKnownLocation().getTime() // old
b = getTime()                        // now

c = b - a        // c is milliseconds since last known location (assuming b and a are numeric)
c / 1000         // seconds since last known location
c / (60*1000)    // minutes
c / (60*60*1000) // hours
```